# iframe size arrangement on bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-5.1

```
<div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Kan Tahlili Sonucu - </h5>
    <div class="ratio ratio-4x3 w-100 w-md-50 text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <iframe src="sonuc.pdf" title="YouTube video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <style>
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .ratio-4x3 {
            width: 50%;
            height: 0;
            padding-bottom: 75%; /* 4:3 aspect ratio */
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .ratio-4x3 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            padding-bottom: 75%; /* 4:3 aspect ratio */
        }
    }
    </style>

    <p class="mt-3">Explanation: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec elit eget justo ullamcorper aliquet. Sed id mauris auctor, ultrices nunc id, lacinia turpis.</p>
</div>
```

In mobile this code works just the way it should be but in desktop it should be a little smaller. Can anyone show me a way to change the size in desktop without touching the mobile? I have almost tried everything but I still could not figure it out.

The problem is in the iframe but not in the media-body. And if you want to bully me please just don't answer the question and leave the page. Thank you.

I wanted it to be smaller in the desktop but it it keeps failing in sizes.